# Apply EuclideanDistance at a certain level in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, euclidean-distance

Please consider:

```
daList = {{{21, 18}, {20, 18}, {18, 17}, {20, 15}}, 
          {{21, 18}, {20, 18}, {21, 14}, {21, 14}}};
```

I would like to compute the distance between each point in the 2 sub-lists of that list:

Yet I need to use a `Function` to apply at the correct level:

```
Function[seqNo, 
         EuclideanDistance[#, {0, 0}] & /@ daList[[seqNo]]] /@ 
         Range[Length@daList]

out = {{3 Sqrt[85], 2 Sqrt[181], Sqrt[613], 25}, {3 Sqrt[85], 2 Sqrt[181], 
        7 Sqrt[13], 7 Sqrt[13]}}
```

Is there a way to avoid this heavy function there?
To specify the level avoiding my Function with seqNo as argument?   :

```
EuclideanDistance[#, {0, 0}] & /@ daList

out={EuclideanDistance[{{21, 18}, {20, 18}, {18, 17}, {20, 15}}, {0, 0}], 
     EuclideanDistance[{{21, 18}, {20, 18}, {21, 14}, {21, 14}}, {0, 0}]}
```

Comment: Couldn't you use the extended form of `Map` to specify the level at which the function is mapped? Have a look at the `MapThread`.

Comment: Yes, I just did not get the syntax when use what I think are pure functions with &. Checked again the help on map, and I could not infer the solution proposed below from it..

Comment: The solution from @Markus Roellig shows what you need. I was on a conference call and didn't have time to provide the full solution myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried the Level specification in Map?

```
Map[EuclideanDistance[#, {0, 0}] &, daList, {2}]
```

gives

```
{{3 Sqrt[85],2 Sqrt[181],Sqrt[613],25},{3 Sqrt[85],2 Sqrt[181],7 Sqrt[13],7 Sqrt[13]}}
```

Comment: This is what i was missing. Could not figure out the syntax from the help, thank you !

Answer (score 6):

To complement the answer of @Markus: if your `daList` is very large and numerical, the following will be much faster (like 30x), although somewhat less general:

```
Sqrt@Total[daList^2,{3}]
```

Here is an example:

```
In[17]:= largeDaList = N@RandomInteger[30,{100000,4,2}];
In[18]:= Map[EuclideanDistance[#,{0,0}]&,largeDaList,{2}]//Short//Timing
Out[18]= {0.953,{{31.7648,34.6699,20.3961,31.305},<<99998>>,{<<18>>,<<2>>,0.}}}

In[19]:= Sqrt@Total[largeDaList^2,{3}]//Short//Timing
Out[19]= {0.031,{{31.7648,34.6699,20.3961,31.305},<<99998>>,{<<18>>,<<2>>,0.}}}
```

The reason is that functions like `Power` and `Sqrt` are `Listable`, and you push the iteration into the kernel. Functions like `Map` can also auto-compile the mapped function in many cases, but apparently not in this case.

**EDIT**

Per OP's request, here is a generalization to the case of non-trivial reference point:

```
refPoint = {3, 5};
Sqrt@Total[#^2, {3}] &@Transpose[Transpose[daList, {3, 2, 1}] - refPoint, {3, 2, 1}]
```

It is still fast, but not as concise as before. For comparison, here is the code based on `Map`- ping, which only needs a trivial modification here:

```
Map[EuclideanDistance[#, refPoint] &, daList, {2}]
```

The performance difference remains of the same order of magnitude, although the vectorized solution slows down a bit due to the need for non-trivial transpositions.

Comment: Thank You Leonid, I guess I could use a change of origin to apply that when i am computing distance from mu points to another point (not the origin {0,0}) And this will be useful, it does yet